# 'this' issue while mapping a List with button reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, this, material-ui

I'm mapping results from a GET request. The mapping works fine. I get each User picture, name and even the correct label on the button. But when I `console.log` on the button, I want to get info of the user. When I click on the button, it gives `user_id` of all users not the particular one.

```
{filteredEmails.map(user => {
  return (
    <List>
      <div className="mail" key={user.user_id}>
        <ListItem
          key={user.user_id}
          disabled={true}
          leftAvatar={
            <Avatar size={80} src={user.picture} />
          }
          rightIconButton={
            <RaisedButton
              label={user.name}
              primary={true}
              key={user.user_id}
              onTouchTap={console.log(user.user_id)}
              style={style} />
          }
        >
          <div className="searchContent" key={user.user_id}>
            <div className="subject">{user.name}</div>
            <br></br>
            <div className="from">{user.email}</div>
            <br></br>
            <div className="subject">{user.identities[0].provider}</div> 
          </div>   
        </ListItem>
      </div>
    </List>
  );
})}
```

[Mapping users picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kc9s.png)

On the above picture, I want to press the button and get `user_id` or `name` of the user. I can't seem to do that.

My guess is problem with `this` context, but I'm unable to fix it so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a function to `onTouchTap` event, and bind the value of user_id to that, by this way whenever user click on button that specific user_id will get passed to that function, then do the `console.log()` inside that it will print the proper value.

Like this:

```
onTouchTap={() => this._handleClick(user.user_id)}
```

Define the `_handleClick` function like this:

```
_handleClick(user_id){
    console.log(user.user_id)
}
```

You also need to define the unique key to each List item inside `map` otherwise it will throw warning, user_id will have the unique values you can use that also.

Write the `map` like this:

```
{filteredEmails.map(user => {
    return (
      <List key={user.user_id}>
          <div className="mail">
              <ListItem
                  key={user.user_id}
                  disabled={true}
                  leftAvatar={
                      <Avatar size={80} src={user.picture} />
                  }
                  rightIconButton={<RaisedButton 
                          label={user.name} 
                          primary={true}  
                          key={user.user_id} 
                          onTouchTap={onTouchTap={() => this._handleClick(user.user_id)}} 
                          style={style} />
                  }
              >
                  <div className="searchContent" key={user.user_id}>
                      <div className="subject">{user.name}</div>
                      <br></br>
                      <div className="from">{user.email}</div>
                      <br></br>
                      <div className="subject">{user.identities[0].provider}</div> 
                  </div>   
              </ListItem>
          </div>
      </List>
    );
})}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I did exactly what you said, and changed this (passed user instead of user_id) '_handleClick(user){
    console.log(user.user_id)
}'

Now i'm getting undefined. also thanks for pointing out Key in list

Comment: BOOM! Sorted. Thanks so much. I needed to pass 'user' instead of 'user.user_id' here 'onTouchTap={() => this._handleClick(user.user_id)}'